How to fix error in google Colab when using model and tokenizer from hugging face: OSError: Can't load tokenizer for 'google/mobilebert-uncased'
from transformers import MobileBertTokenizer, MobileBertForSequenceClassification
model_name = "google/mobilebert-uncased"
num_labels = 4  # Adjust this based on the number of distinct intents you have
tokenizer = MobileBertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = MobileBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name, num_labels=len(label_encoder.classes_))
getting this error:
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 10>()
8 num_labels = 4  # Adjust this based on the number of distinct intents you have
9
---> 10 tokenizer = MobileBertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
11 model = MobileBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name, num_labels=len(label_encoder.classes_))
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, cache_dir, force_download, local_files_only, token, revision, trust_remote_code, *init_inputs, **kwargs)
2030
2031         if all(full_file_name is None for full_file_name in resolved_vocab_files.values()):
-> 2032             raise EnvironmentError(
2033                 f"Can't load tokenizer for '{pretrained_model_name_or_path}'. If you were trying to load it from "
2034                 "'https://huggingface.co/models', make sure you don't have a local directory with the same name. "
OSError: Can't load tokenizer for 'google/mobilebert-uncased'. If you were trying to load it from 'https://huggingface.co/models', make sure you don't have a local directory with the same name. Otherwise, make sure 'google/mobilebert-uncased' is the correct path to a directory containing all relevant files for a MobileBertTokenizer tokenizer.
The code runs perfectly fine on jupyter notebook but takes a long time. it is supposed to take the model and tokenizer from transformers and just get running

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
